# Maven deploy fails for Apache Archiva

Tags: apache, deployment, maven-2, timeout, archiva

I have a Maven project which generates a 413.06 KB jar file. I have to deploy it on Apache Archiva based managed repository. I have tried to deploy different versions, and it created required layout and structure, uploaded some files, even it uploaded that jar with 200~ KB. every time the jar file size changes but always it fails to upload 413.06 KB jar file.

Information:-

1. I am running standalone Archiva
2. I have given guest account to Global Repository Manager & "Repository Manager - MYREPO"
3. I have also tried a separate account in Archiva with "Repository Manager - MYREPO" rights and configured it in maven's settings.xml file to set custom timeout.

I am getting following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
(default-deploy) on project SharedshelfRepository: Error deploying artifact: Transfer error:
The server did not respond within the configured timeout. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that might be maven-deploy-plugin issue, resources plugin itself needs several dependencies,try manually jar nad p

Answer (score 0):

What version of Maven are you using? You might try 3.0.4 as it has a different HTTP library. I'm also not sure if there's more context for what was happening when it timed out (it seems more request oriented rather than deploy oriented, and deploy does request some metadata).

I can't see that you'd need to alter the timeout, as none of the defaults should apply to such a small file. How long does it take to fail?

Comment: I am already using 3.0.4, this has been resolved by running from CLI instead of eclipse.